# AEM/Sling: How do I implement dynamic sling selector?

Tags: aem, sling

**TLDR**: I want setup an AEM page that accepts firstname and lastname as parameter using an SEO friendly URL.

Going to www.host.com/mycontent.richard.williams.html will display information relevant to Richard Williams.

If I go to www.host.com/mycontent.john.smith.html, the page will display information relevant to John Smith.

---

**SEO friendly example**: www.host.com/mycontent.richard.williams.html

**not SEO friendly example**: www.host.com/mycontent.html?firstname=richard&lastname=williams

---

So I've been following this guide (not sure if this is the best example/guide to help me): http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/sling-servlet-in-aem/

And while it works well for my the example

```
@SlingServlet(resourceTypes="geometrixx/components/hompepage", selectors={"firstname","lastname"}, extensions="html",methods="GET", metatype=true)
```

I am trying to make it dynamic.

At the moment, I can only access the servlet if access via: http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en.firstname.lastname.html

I want to make firstname and lastname dynamic parameters/selectors. Like if for example I want to pass the values "richard.williams", I can then use: http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en.richard.williams.html

if I try to use http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en.richard.williams.html  right now, I get a blank page.

So basically I want to use selectors for passing parameter values to my page.

Any ideas how this can be done?

ps. At the moment, I only testing/experimenting in my local instance of AEM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selectors in sling don't provide the functionality of placing variables in the URL path. i.e. you cannot add {pathParam} like in Spring to sling servlet URL.

In general, selectors are not recommended to be used like an input to a function. They are to be used more like file extensions.
For eg. A request to /mycontent.html returns the same resource as /mycontent.mobile.html. The only difference being, the latter requests for a mobile friendly version.

Request params on the other hand serve the purpose of providing inputs to the servlet.

---

I cannot think of any direct way to attach a servlet to dynamic paths in sling. You can try using `suffix`, they are cacheable in the dispatcher, but I can't comment on the SEO friendliness of using `suffix`.

Consider this URI -  `/mycontent/user.json/john/smith`

Register a servlet using the path `/mycontent/user` and you can use 
`String[] names = request.getRequestPathInfo().getSuffix().split(suffix, '/')`
to retrieve the suffix contents.

Take a look at answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984706/is-it-possible-to-place-variables-into-a-resource-path-within-a-sling-servlet). Sling `ResourceProvider` and integrating with `jax-rs` are other ways you can accomplish this.

Comment: Suffix are ok from SEO perspective at least google doesn't have any issues with it. Not sure about other engines though.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this would be feasible with the use of `OptingServlet` (see https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html#optingservlet-interface)

Your `accepts` method could easily recognise the expected `resourceType` and react appropriately.

As mentioned in the docs this approach is discouraged and the solution proposed by Subhash to use suffixes seems way more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a components which reads selector from the request and add that compoent to en.html